# tf2 problem on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: games, steam

Hello Ubuntu community!!!

as soon as I found out that Steam is available on Linux, formatted my win7 and installed Ubuntu 12.10.

Everything works fine, had some minor trouble with nvidia but fixed it.

Have this old desktop PC: Intel C2D E4600 2,4 x2,
                          Geforce 9800GT,
                          2 GB of ram

Installed Steam, installed TF2 and tried it out. Everything starts great, even faster then win7. Main menu of Tf2 looks fine. Trouble starts when I try to join servers. First thing I noticed is that it takes a long time when retrieving server info.. when in game the lagg is unbelievable, no way the game can be played. 
Its like my GPU is way too weak for this game..

The thing is that I played it on win7 with these same exact settings on 1440x900, (you can tell by the little stars that those are recommended settings) and game was running without any problem even in biggest fights.

http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/4561/2013021900001.jpg

Also tryed lowering everything to low/disable and its the same only with really ugly graphics.
Using 310 drivers for nvidia provided by Software Sources.

Please help, willing to try any advice.

**SOLVED!!!**

this helped:  http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-pangolin-nvidia.html

to everyone that has same issue: just lunch Nvidia x server settings, under open gl settings turn off Sync to VBlank.  :)

that was sucking my CPU dry, was not GPU after all.

now the game runs without any problems.

only thing now is the long "retrieving server info" time.. but I'm sure Steam and Ubuntu will fix that soon enough.

Thanx everyone! Ubuntu rocks!!

Comment: Please add the solution as an new answer and tag that answer as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I saw nVidia had experimental 340 drivers under Software Sources on 12.10, so it might be worth trying those and seeing if they fix the graphical issues.

As for retrieving server info taking longer, I'm also seeing this issue on my Win7 machine.  I assume that the game's GCF files may have gotten fragmented during recent updates... I know on Windows you can defragment the cache files for a game in its Properties page.